# Big Query table not changing when run

Tags: google-bigquery

I am a complete novice to Big Query, completing my Google Analytics Capstone Project. I have cleaned my data (somewhat) but I am completely lost as my table does not change. I have deleted inaccurate data but my table remains the same number of rows - unadjusted (containing 5, 803,721) pre-cleaning and post-cleaning:

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=476906707346:b234197414754d0a89901c6c7a5c960f

I have only run my queries, have not selected anything else.

Am I missing an 'export new table' feature. When I click the 'Go to Table' button in Big query after querying, nothing opens.

Thank you,

Sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon quick look, it seems like you are not saving your transformations in temporary tables or sub-queries. You can use the [WITH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#sql_syntax) clause to save your mid-transformations then [write your final query results to a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results).